# Using System.Printing in VB 2013 Express

Tags: wpf

I'm just starting to learn printing in wpf with VB 2013 express.  However, I cannot even use

```
imports system.printing
```

to get started.  I get this error message:

> Warning    1   Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'System.printing' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a reference to System.Printing assembly in your project.  To do this: Click on Project / Add Reference, Select Assemblies then check the System.Printing assembly.  You will no longer get the error message.